# Solving Nonlinear System for two variables

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have an optimization like below:

$\text{ minimize } \sum_k - w_k\log_2 x_k   $

$\text{subject to: }  x_k \leq q , k =1,2, \cdots, N .$

$\hspace{20mm} 0 \leq w_k \leq 1$

I can form the Lagrange of the problem as below:

$L(x,w, \lambda) =  \sum_{k=1}^{N} - w_k \log_2 x_k + \sum_{k=1}^{N} \lambda_k  (x_k -q) + \sum_{k=1}^{N}v_k w_k$

But How can I find KKT conditions for this? Moreover, How can I solve the problem analytically from there? I know I can solve it through some nonlinear optimization solver software but for now I am only interested in solving the problem analytically so that I can get an exact form of x.

Is there any better way to solve this for optimal value of $(w, R)$? Any hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: Note that $x_k \leq q \implies \log_2 x_k \leq \log_2 q$ since $\log$ is monotone. You can simplify the problem statement by working with $y_k = \log_2 x_k$ instead. The problem then reduces to maximizing $L = {\bf w} \cdot {\bf y}$ where ${\bf y}$ denotes the vector $(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_N)$ subject to $w_k \in [0,1]$ and $y_k \leq \log_2 q$.

Comment: thank u @Winther... but that objective function still remains nonlinear, is not it?

Comment: That function is linear in $y_k$: $L=w_1y_1 + w_2y_2 + \ldots + w_k y_k$. To solve the problem note that the condition on ${\bf y}$ only depends on each $y_k$ individually (there is no mixing between different terms like $y_1y_2 \leq 1$). This makes it very easy as $L$ will attains the maximum when all the different terms $w_k y_k$ attains their individual maximum.

Comment: the problem is: here both $y_k$ and $w_k$ are variables. So I want to optimize the value of both variables to attain max. in that case can I consider it as a linear prob??

Comment: Both $y_k$ and $w_k$ are independent of each other in the constraints (meaning the constraint on $y_k$ is independent of $w_k$ and vice versa) so first try to answer this question: if $0\leq w \leq 1$ and $y \leq a$ what is the maximum value of $w y$? (there are in fact two cases here: $a<0$ and $a>0$). If you can answer this you can answer the full question since each $w_k y_k$ are independent of each other.

Comment: I've dropped the convex optimization tag for you, since this is not.